# Solving a sextic equation

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

> Solve the following equation for real $x$. $$(x^2+x-2)^3+(2x^2-x-1)^3=27(x^2-1)^3$$

---

I tried this, $$(x^2+x-2)^3+(2x^2-x-1)^3=27(x^2-1)^3$$
$$(x^2+x-2+2x^2-x-1)[(x^2+x-2)^2+(2x^2-x-1)^2-(x^2+x-2)(2x^2-x-1)]=(3x^2-3)^3$$
$$(3x^2-3)[(x^2+x-2)^2+(2x^2-x-1)^2-(x^2+x-2)(2x^2-x-1)]=(3x^2-3)^3$$
Cancelling $3x^2-3$, $$(x^2+x-2)^2+(2x^2-x-1)^2-(x^2+x-2)(2x^2-x-1)=(3x^2-3)^2$$
Now I am clueless. What should I do now?

Comment: Note that by canceling $3x^2-3$ you are loosing $-1$ and $1$ as solutions.

Comment: You can try to factor left and right hand sides, this yields $9(x+1)(x^2+x+1)(x-1)^3 = 27(x-1)^3(x+1)^3.$ Then cancelling out common factors (note that these give rise to solutions to) you will be left with the easier $x^2+x+1 = 3(x+1)^2,$ which can be solved quite easily.

Comment: Since $RHS=(3x^2-3)^3$, the equation can be written as $A^3+B^3=(A+B)^3$ where $A=x^2+x-2$ and $B=2x^2-x-1$.

Comment: By inspection, your last equation still has a root $x=1$, so after you remove that remaining  $(x-1)$ factor you are left with a cubic, then try the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to solve it, which will "luckily" work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cancelled $3x^2-3$, so two solutions are coming from $3x^2-3$. They are $\pm1$.

And let me substitute $x^2+x-2=a, 2x^2-x-1=b$.

Then your last equation turns into $a^2+b^2-ab=(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$.

Since $ab=0$, the another solutions comes from $a=0, b=0$.

They are $-2, -\frac12$.

So answer is...

$$
x=-2, -1, -\frac12, 1
$$

Answer (score 0):

We can write:
$$(x^2+x-2)^3=(x-1)^3\cdot(x+2)^3$$
$$(2x^2-x-1)^3=(x-1)^3\cdot(2x+1)^3$$
$$(x^2-1)^3=(x-1)^3\cdot(x+1)^3$$
Now, we see a common factor of $(x-1)^3$ that we can simplify (note that $\mathcal{M}\mathcal{a}(1)=3$).

When $x\neq 1$, the equation becomes:
$$(2x+1)^3+(x+2)^2=27(x+1)^3\,\,\leftrightarrow\,\, 2x^3+7x^2+5x+2=0$$

We can easily factor the polymomial:
$$2x^3+7x^2+5x+2=0\,\, \leftrightarrow\,\,(x+1)(2x^2+5x+2)=0\,\,\leftrightarrow\,\, (x+1)\cdot\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot(x+2)=0$$

Those three solutions have $\mathcal{Ma}=1$ each.

Comment: Why $x^2+3x+1=(x-\frac12)(x+2)$??

Comment: @Nightflight: I'm sorry. I made a mistake. See my edits. Thanks.